# Plotting Shapefile on ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, spatial, ggmap

I am attempting to plot several shapefiles on top of a map generated through ggmap. This is working well, however I want to constrain the view area to the shapefile (and not rely on the `zoom` argument in `ggmaps`). I've done this by getting the bounding box and passing it as an argument in `ggplot`'s `coord_cartesian` While this works, I am getting some tearing issues on the edges of the map - most specifically on the western portion. I've tried adjusting the x-y coordinates manually but it seems to only severely distort the picture.

[image: Detroit Shapefile Map]

My thoughts are to zoom out slightly to allow the entire shapefile to be plotted in the area, but I can't seem to figure it out. It's also possible I am going about this entirely in the wrong way.

Here's the code I used to generate the map. The shapefile can be downloaded [here](https://data.detroitmi.gov/api/geospatial/gx6d-7i83?method=export&format=Shapefile)

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggmap)
library(rgdal)
library(broom)

# Read in shapefile, project into long-lat
# Create 'tbox' which is a minimum bounding box around the shapefile

tracts <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "CensusTracts2010") %>%
  spTransform("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84")
tbox <- bbox(tracts)

# Plot data
tract_plot <- tidy(tracts)

DetroitMap <- qmap("Detroit", zoom = 11)

DetroitMap + geom_polygon(data = tract_plot, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = id), color = "black", fill = NA) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(tbox[1,1], tbox[1,2]),
                  ylim = c(tbox[2,1], tbox[2,2]))
```

Comment: What happens when you use `coord_map()`?

Answer (score 0):

I followed your workflow, which resulted in the same problem as you mentioned above. Then I changed the zoom on the `qmap` option from 11 to 10 and it resulted in a much better picture, although you do lose some of the place names but you can add those in manually yourself with `annotate`:

```
DetroitMap <- qmap("Detroit", zoom = 10)

DetroitMap + geom_polygon(data = tract_plot, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = id), color = "black", fill = NA) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(tbox[1,1], tbox[1,2]),
                    ylim = c(tbox[2,1], tbox[2,2]))
```

[image]